# Twig if/else not working

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm not sure why my code isn't executing. I know that it should be working this way but all that happens now is that it doesn't do the else portion.

In debugging I know descriptions is not null and descriptions show for those that have it.

```
{% if descriptions is not null %}
{{ dump(descriptions) }}
    {% for description in descriptions %}
        <td>{{ description.productDesciption }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <td> 
        <a href = "{{ path('description') }}">Create a Description for this Product</a>
    </td>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you get any different results if you use this if statement instead? `{% if descriptions %}`

Comment: I figured it out. I was testing if an array is null which is was so I had to test the length/count the array.

Comment: Ah, I see. Glad you sorted it out. There's a handy list of values on the [docs page](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/if.html) for what values evaluate to true/false too (it's near the very bottom of the page). Technically an empty array will evaluate to `false` in an if statement, which is kinda handy.

Comment: You can also test if something 'is not empty'. This will check, if the variable is not null, not an empty string and not an emtpy array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simplify using the [The else Clause](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-else-clause) of the for statement:

```
{% for description in descriptions %}
     <td>
        {{ description.productDesciption }}
     </td>
{% else %}
     <td> 
        <a href = "{{ path('description') }}">Create a Description for this Product</a>
    </td>
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this help

Comment: A small sidenote: When you foreach over a non array/iteratable/generator type, you would get a warning in PHP. In twig you won't have to worry about that. If you do for/else on a null value, everything will work fine.

Comment: I like this answer a lot, I didn't know you could do this and it worked for me too so I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `if` into `for` loop.

```
{% for description in descriptions if descriptions is not null %}
   <td>
    {{ description.productDesciption }}
   </td>
{% else %}
   <td> 
      <a href = "{{ path('description') }}">Create a Description for this Product</a>
   </td>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yes you can do this, but check my comment on the other answer. This if check is redundant for this case. The if statement in a for is meant to work as a filter on your set. In your example it would do this if not null in every loop instead of around it.